# Wordpress Blog RSS Feed Problems

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I have been posting on my blog http://www.prashantraju.com/ since Jan 2010 however for some reason when I subscribe to my feed http://www.prashantraju.com/feed (which is redirected to http://feeds.feedburner.com/AnalyseThis) it doesn't show my latest post?

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it shows to me ... probably you are seeing a Cached page of your feed in your browser.

Comment: hmm, i just subscribed again and now im getting duplicate entries and my latest post is still coming up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this querystring to the Feed Url.

http://feeds.feedburner.com/AnalyseThis?format=xml

Answer (score 0):

It may be best to turn off your feedburner plugin that redirects your feed to feedburner. From there you'll be able to see if you're actual feed is up to date and if there's any difference between your feed and feedburner's. If there is, it's usually just a matter of updating your feed once you log into feedburner or an invalid character will sometimes throw it off. To find out if it's a character, try validating your feed - http://validator.w3.org/feed/ - if it's not valid it usually will give you an idea on what line number it's failing, which then should tell you which post it's having a difficult time with.